# I was messing with CompizConfig and now I lost the top panel

Tags: panel

I was messing with CompizConfig and I lost the top panel where it tells the time and has the exit buttons and whatnot. Could someone help me get the top panel back? Thank you.

Comment: I actually found out how to do it.  If you go back to CompizConfig and go to the desktop area, you can find the Ubuntu Unity Plug-in.  If you click on that and then enable it on the side, you're top panel comes back along with everything that was on it before like: the exit button and battery life as well as time, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to reset Unity. You can do that by installing dconf-tools

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

then run

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
```

which will reset all the dconf settings for compiz.

then you need to restart unity which can be done with this command

```
setsid unity
```